# How to combine similar rows in a data frame in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

In this dataframe I have repeating Date values

```
df <- data.frame(
  Date_Time = c("2023-06-14 09:43:06", "2023-06-14 09:43:09", "2023-06-14 09:43:12",
                "2023-06-14 09:43:06", "2023-06-14 09:43:09", "2023-06-14 09:43:12"),
  Heat_Capacity = c(219857, 219857, 219857, NA, NA, NA),
  Heat_Transfer_Coefficient = c(NA, NA, NA, 0, 0, 0)
)
```

I'm trying to get output like this:

```
Date_Time                              Heat_Capacity      Heat_Transfer_Coefficient
1 2023-06-14 09:43:06                   219857                     0
2 2023-06-14 09:43:09                   219857                     0
3 2023-06-14 09:43:12                   219857                     0
```

Comment: How do you define "similar"? Could you be a little more specific on the logic?

Comment: I meant same values. As you can see in the Date_Time column values are repeating

Comment: What I mean is: if there is a duplicate in `Date_Time`, do you keep the first row (maybe another row)? Do the values of the other columns `Heat_Capacity` or `Heat_Transfer_Coefficient` matter when picking which row to keep? It looks like you're taking values from both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could `group_by` on your Date_Time and `summarise` `across` the columns by using `na.omit` to merge the rows to remove the NA like this:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Date_Time) %>%
  summarise(across(Heat_Capacity:Heat_Transfer_Coefficient, ~ na.omit(.x)))
#> # A tibble: 3 × 3
#>   Date_Time           Heat_Capacity Heat_Transfer_Coefficient
#>   <chr>                       <dbl>                     <dbl>
#> 1 2023-06-14 09:43:06        219857                         0
#> 2 2023-06-14 09:43:09        219857                         0
#> 3 2023-06-14 09:43:12        219857                         0
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You can use `tidyr::fill` with direction "downup" by date/time:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(Date_Time) %>%
  fill(everything(), .direction = "downup") %>%
  distinct()
```

Output:

```
  Date_Time           Heat_Capacity Heat_Transfer_Coefficient
  <chr>                       <dbl>                     <dbl>
1 2023-06-14 09:43:06        219857                         0
2 2023-06-14 09:43:09        219857                         0
3 2023-06-14 09:43:12        219857                         0
```